# How to store additional data that is related to core data

Tags: custom-post-types, database, hooks, actions, wpdb

Long story short, I am going to be building a web application with WordPress as the framework. We have to use WordPress, I cannot suggest a different framework.

The application will have users with various roles, and all sorts of custom data and post types. I will use custom post types where I can, but some aspects of the project seem like the best thing to do is create my own tables inside the WordPress database, or, use an entirely separate database.

**For example** - A single admin can upload up to 6 PDFs on a special admin page. I would want the user to just upload the media like normal. Then I would consider having table called `special_report_pdfs` or whatever, and have attachment ids stored there so I can reference "the 4th special pdf" later. This is just one example. I can provide more if needed.

I know adding columns to WordPress tables is considered bad. It also seems like adding tables to the WordPress database is also considered bad? Or does it make the most sense in my case? Is using a separate database acceptable?

My worry is what if there is no hook available for a certain action. From my previous example, anytime a PDF file was deleted from the media library, I would need to hook in, and potentially connect to the other database and delete the reference in the `special_report_pdfs` table. If there is no hook for that, is there any way to update foreign keys in my database when certain things in the wordpress database change? Maybe that is why using a separate database is not recommended?

Comment: every data structure can be stored in the core wordpress tables with custom post type, post meta, user meta, site options, etc. the only reason to create new tables is when you have a huge quantity of data that need better performances.

Comment: Really?! That's great! Yeah I don't imagine millions of users or rows of data. I didn't think to use the meta stuff. This could probably be the accepted answer honestly